# Mapping headers into PySpark sql Dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am working on Azure Databricks, and my scenario is the following:

I'm reading (using: spark.read.format("csv").options().load()) a CSV file stored in Blob storage. Such file contains 1000 columns/variables(one thousand) but data and header are separated (different files). I want to map headers into the pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame but my approach took 1.18 hours.

This is the approached  I used.

```
oldNames = df.schema.names
newNames = ["name", "lastName" ,.........] #Just an example
dfMap= reduce(lambda df, idx: df.withColumnRenamed(oldColumns[idx], newColumns[idx]), range(len(oldColumns)), df)
```

I am sure there is a faster way/better approach to accomplish such a task.

Thanks!